# C# Net Core: After enabling Cors in API, it still states blocked by CORS policy

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, cors

I created a backend Net Core API which works in VS and Postman.
However, when creating an Angular CLI front end, I receive this error. It does not make sense, since I enabled Add Cors for AllowAnyOrigin Below.

**Angular error:**

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:xxxx/api/values' from origin 'http://localhost:xxxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddCors((options =>
            { options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());}));

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors();
            // Shows UseCors with CorsPolicyBuilder.
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Try this https://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the CORS middleware to the pipeline as well:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
    // Other middleware
}
```

When you call AddCors(), you are adding the services needed by the CORS middleware, as well as defining a policy.
But you need to apply the policy in the middleware pipeline as well.